# Qt Creator / QMake Linker Libraries

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake, sfml

I'm using SFML, and I want to use Qt Creator in conjunction with it. When I'm compiling manually, I supply the following arguments to the linker `-lsfmlsystem -lsfmlwindow`.

How do I do this if I'm using Qt Creator and (I think) QMake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/sfml -lsfmlsystem -lsfmlwindow
```

to the .pro file.

You can open project files with QtCreator from the Projects view of the sidebar or searching for it via Ctrl-K. (BTW, the sidebar is *not* the list of icons down the left, it's the pane to the right of that which can be shown/hidden with Alt-0.)